# python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory - docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm seeing the above error when I try to run my docker image. Below are the screenshots of my docker file and the directory structure.

[image: Dockerfile]

[image]

Comment: I can't run that PNG file to try to reproduce your issue.  Can you delete both images, and replace them with the actual source code necessary to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

As you have already specified the `WORKDIR` in the `Dockerfile`. Dont' copy your files to `/`.

Change your command to

```
COPY . .   # If you want to copy whole folder into container
```

and as well `CMD` command to

```
CMD ["python", "src/main.py"]
```